# Union of partial ring is not a partial ring

Tags: ring-theory

I am looking for a counterexample for the following statement "the union of a partial ring is not necessarily a partial ring"

Comment: Since it is apparently not a common definition: what do you call a partial ring?

Comment: If R a ring and S a non-empty subset of R. we call S a subring of R if S itself is a ring for the operations of R.

Comment: Is a partial ring a subring that doesn't have to contain 1?

Comment: It’s the same as subring i think

Comment: @wisk Doesn't need identity at all?

Comment: "The union of subrings is not necessarily a subring" amounts to "There exists an example of two subrings whose union is not a subring."  It is nonsense to ask for a counterexample to this statement: it is true.  So you could be either asking for an *example* that illustrates it can happen, or that it can fail.

Comment: i ask for a counterexample that shows that the union of subrings is a subring...